# Liferay: User-Notification for Workflow approvers

Tags: notifications, liferay, workflow

I'm trying to send a notification when the workflow is approved, however, the user who created the content article does not receive notification.

Can anyone help me? thanks

```
<state>
    <name>approved</name>
    <metadata>
        <![CDATA[
            {"xy":[380,51]}
        ]]>
    </metadata>
    <actions>
        <action>
            <name>approve</name>
            <script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil;
                    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;

                    WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);
                ]]>
            </script>
            <script-language>groovy</script-language>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </action>

        <notification>
            <name>Approval Notification</name>
            <template>Your submission was approved</template>
            <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
            <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
            <recipients>
                <user />
            </recipients>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </notification>

    </actions>
</state>
```

Comment: which version of liferay are you using?

Comment: for liferay 6.1 i have found a blog may of some help: http://www.liferay.com/web/igor.beslic/blog/-/blogs/workflow-in-action-setup-email-notifications

Comment: I am using the version 6.2-ce